# Kohana 3 pagination

Tags: php, pagination, kohana, kohana-3

I'm really lost on how pagination works in kohana 3. Is there a good example of pagination in Kohana 3 anywhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
        // Get the total count of articles
    $count = $this
        ->_profil
        ->articles
        ->count_all();

    // Create the pagination object
    $pagi = Pagination::factory(array(
        'items_per_page'    =>  4,
        'total_items'       =>  $count,
    ));

    // Find actual articles
    $articles = $this->_profil
        ->articles
        ->join_categories()
        ->order_by('id','DESC')
        ->limit($pagi->items_per_page)
        ->offset($pagi->offset)
        ->find_all();
```

and then in the View, you just do

```
echo $pagi; // ofc, after passing the Pagination object to view
```

What happens here is Pagination class using it's View's __toString() magic method to render html needed to display pagination. All pagination params can be modified when creating the object (passing appropriate keys to the array passed to factory() method in our case).

Default key for pagination is "page" (query string), while you can modify that as well. Pagination also has a default config, which you can override by copying it to application/config folder.

Enjoy using it :)

Comment: also ORM has useful `count_last_query()` method for counting result rows.

Comment: though I wouldn't rely on that method too much when having a complicated query :) This way we can reuse the count query as well, by adding reset(FALSE) before the counting occurs.

Comment: The `reset(FALSE)` method worked really nice, I think it saved my afternoon, heh.

Comment: Don't forget echo $pagi->render() or you will get a to string error in kohana 3.1... Just noting for future searches since I just used this answer to help my ko 3.1 problem. Thanks

Comment: @KaiQing __toString() calls the render() method anyways, though exceptions inside of it can't be caught

Answer (score 3):

In Kohana 3.1 pagination is not included.  Download the module and put it in the **modules** folder. Enable the module in your **application/bootstrap.php** .This is my controller page. For further configuration  copy the provided config file from **modules/pagination/config/pagination.php** to **application/config/pagination.php**

```
    $per_page =2;
    $page_num = $this->request->param('page', 1);
    $offset   = ($page_num - 1) * $per_page;
    $view =View::factory('image/imagelist')->bind('page_links',$page_links)->bind('results', $results)->bind('pagination', $pagination);

     // Get the total count of records in the database
     $userid = Auth::instance()->get_user()->pk();  
     $count=ORM::factory('user_image')->where('app_userid','=',$userid)->count_all(); 


     // Create an instance of Pagination class and set values
     $pagination = Pagination::factory(array( 

      'total_items'    => $count,
      'current_page'   => array('source' => 'image/imagelist', 'key' => 'page'), 
      'items_per_page' => $per_page,
      'offset'  =>  $offset,
      'view'    =>  'pagination/basic'
  ));


      // Load specific results for current page
  $results = DB::select()->from('user_images')
            ->where('app_userid','=',$userid)
            ->order_by('image_id','ASC')
            ->limit($pagination->items_per_page)
            ->offset($pagination->offset)->execute();

 $page_links = $pagination;
 $this->template->content=$view->render();
```

You may get error ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: `Request::$uri`. in the pagination class (module). In order to fix  fix it

Use `Request::current()->uri()` instead of `Request::current()->uri`

Answer (score 2):

You can find some decent docs in the [unofficial Kohana wiki](http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=how_to_use_the_pagination_module).